# How does one report the line on which an error occured in Postgres/plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, plpgsql

I have been using something more or less like this in postgres to emulate how, in SQL Server, I have used Try/Catch blocks with transactions that can be rolled back in the Catch if an error is found:

```
do $$
begin
[SQL here]

exception when others then
    raise notice 'Error in insert statement ---> % %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE LINE;
end;    

$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Is there a way to report the line where the error occurred, like "ERROR_LINE()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On some modern PostgreSQL, you can use `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS` statement. There is not possibility to get linenumber, but you can get a call context, where lineno is included:

```
postgres=> DO $$
DECLARE 
  a int DEFAULT 0;
  _c text;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    PERFORM 10/a;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS _c = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'context: >>%<<', _c;
  END;
END;
$$;
NOTICE:  00000: context: >>SQL statement "SELECT 10/a"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at PERFORM<<
LOCATION:  exec_stmt_raise, pl_exec.c:3041
DO
```

Comment: Just so everyone knows. This will only work on 9.2 and beyond. I even confirmed it doesn't work on 9.1

Answer (score 1):

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
a int DEFAULT 0;
      m_sqlstate text;
      m_message text;
      m_context text;
      m_PG_EXCEPTION_HINT text;
BEGIN
      PERFORM 10/a;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
      m_sqlstate = returned_sqlstate,
      m_message = message_text,
      m_context = pg_exception_context,
      m_PG_EXCEPTION_HINT = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
         RAISE NOTICE 'sqlstate: %', m_sqlstate; --show for error code .
         RAISE NOTICE 'message: %', m_message;
         RAISE NOTICE 'context: %', m_context;
         RAISE NOTICE 'The exception detail: %', m_PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
END
$$;
```

---

Result:

```
NOTICE:  sqlstate: 22012
NOTICE:  message: division by zero
NOTICE:  context: SQL statement "SELECT 10/a"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at PERFORM
NOTICE:  The exception detail:
DO
```

- Manual [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS) for get diagnostic stack.   Especially check
  **Table 43.2. Error Diagnostics Items**
- PostgreSQL Error Codes In manual [appendix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html#ERRCODES-TABLE), that is not easy to
  find.

---

As you can see that: `pg_exception_context` will report the line occurred.
tested on **PostgreSQL version: 14**